# Is there a way to assign damage to multiple defenders?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012

I have noticed that whenever the computer blocks with multiple defenders, the computer clearly decides which distribution of damage is most advantageous.  It does not seem to matter what order I assign the defenders; no matter whether I assign them first, last, or in the middle, the damage will be assigned in such a way as to destroy my most important defender, leaving only the weakest defender if there isn't enough damage to destroy all of them.

Is there a way that I can assign the damage to defenders in a similar fashion, when I am attacking?  Because right now it seems to default to the least beneficial distribution for me when there is not enough damage to destroy all defenders (i.e. the weakest defenders are killed first, in rather an opposite fashion to what happens when I'm the defender).  Is this biased both ways in favor of the computer, or is there a way for me to enable further control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the normal tabletop card-game, if there are multiple creatures blocking one creature, it's the **attacking-player** who gets to choose what order to assign the damage.

In Magic 2012: DotP, when you are the attacker, by default the computer chooses an order for you *(to keep the game "simple")*.  You can however change it so that **you** get to decide the order every time by going to Settings --> Advanced --> uncheck *"Auto assign damage."*

Answer (score 0):

From [the MTG wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering_rules):

> Once the attacking player declares attackers, the defending player chooses which creatures he or she will block with. A creature must be untapped in order for it to block. Unlike attacking, the act of blocking does not cause the blocking creatures to tap, and creatures with summoning sickness can block. Each creature can only block a single attacker(unless specifically indicated on the card, such as: Two-Headed Giant of Foriys), **although multiple creatures can be used to block a single attacking creature. In this case, the attacker chooses the order of the blocking creatures.** The ordering becomes relevant in the combat damage step.

Now how you actually do this in Duels of the Planeswalkers I don't remember, but you should get to choose the order of blocks when you're attacking and being blocked by multiple creatures

Also, I know this is not directly answering your question of how to do it in the game, but thought it could still be relevant.

Comment: that is weird, the damage should be assigned in the same order you choose the blocks

Comment: It could be a bug, wouldn't be the first one I've seen with that game.  I would just say verify you're not overlooking a first strike or some other ability.

Comment: A bug (or just a "let's 'simplify' it" mentality) was my first thought, but it wouldn't be the first interface option I simply just didn't find.  It is definitely not a first strike issue, as first strike is clearly displayed with a separate round of attacks.

Comment: Information on how it should work in paper MtG is great, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It seems like you're saying you can't choose the order of how you block, which is true as I've stated above the attacker chooses the block order when multiple creatures block a single one.  What you should be able to do is that when you are *Attacking* and they block with multiple creatures, choose the order in which the creatures block

Comment: @OrigamiRobot as I originally understood the question it did not answer it directly as I stated in the answer but still provided relevant information to the issue, however, as question is becoming more clarified it does provide an answer.  -- You don't get to choose the block order if you're defending

Comment: Right, you are basically saying "I agree.  It should work like this, but it doesn't.  I don't know why."  This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It works how its supposed to is what i'm saying please re-read what I said.  The game is correct in that he should not get to choose block order. Unless you're asking me to provide an answer of why something doesn't work like its not supposed to.

Comment: **Is there a way that I can assign the damage to defenders in a similar fashion, when I am attacking?**  If you are attacking, you *should* get to choose the order blockers receive damage. If the game does not let him do so, it is **incorrect**.

Comment: @BrianColvin Sorry, I got side-tracked and posted some misleading comments here.  Yes, you can choose the order in which you block *when defending*, but those selections do not impact the order in which damage is dealt. You are correct in that this is working as it should be. However, the question I am asking is "is there a way for me, *as attacker* to determine the order in which damage is assigned when my opponent defends with multiple creatures?

Comment: @Beofett - I believe the answer is 'no, the defender always gets to decide this' (with the possible exception of banding, but I forget how this works under modern rules, and maybe deathtouch but that's different also).

Comment: @Shinrai in my experience, the answer is "no, the *computer* always gets to decide this".  This applies for both attacking and defending.  My question is "is there any way to override this?".