# How do I choose the order in which my blockers are chosen?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

Under normal circumstances, an attacker can be blocked by multiple blockers. However, I have not been able to find an explicit way to choose which blocker I can pick to be the cannon fodder. For example, when I block a 3/4 creature with a 2/2 and a 3/2 creature, logic dictates that I should choose to block with the 2/2 first, so that my 3/2 would survive; the game quite often disagrees by picking the stronger of the two to block first. Is there a definite way to make this happen?

Comment: The attacker chooses the order to assign damage, not the blocker.

Comment: Yes, I figured this out from the answers. I marked Novarg's answer as accepted because he mentioned settings. I was actually having the same issue with attackers having no control over which blocker to assign damage first, which is what led me to think blockers had control over the assignment of damage rather than attackers. It's all an interesting chain of events that originates from this option being turned on (automatic) by default.

Comment: FYI here is the same question (with the same answer) for MTG 2012:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50781

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be a way to choose which creature will block first. There is however a possibility to choose a blocking creature to attack first(so if you attack with a 3/4 creature and enemy blocks with 2/2 and 3/2 creatures, YOU can choose which creature to attack first).

To enable choosing creatures, you have to enable it in the settings. Go to Help & Options -> Settings -> Advanced, and uncheck the Order Blockers Automatically option.

Source: MTGDotP 2012 and 2013 (I don't think that it changed)

Comment: A good answer, especially because it attacks the root of the question, which is that the Q is confused by the automatic resolution for attacker choice.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [rules](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Declare_blockers_step) (from Innistrad upwards), the way the damage is assigned is as follows:

The owner of the attacking creature chooses the order of blocking creatures which the attacking creature will deal damage to. So if the attacking player has a 10/10 and the defender has one 5/10 and five 5/1 and blocks with all of them (ignore that it's a stupid idea to block like this), the attacker can decide to who he will deal damage - logically, he would choose the five 5/1 creatures and the last 5/10 would just soak up the last 5 points.

Similarly, if a blocking creature would be blocking more than one attacker, the owner of the blocking creature decides the order of the creatures it's blocking in which they are dealt damage by the blocking creature.

So, the short answer comes to **No, it would be against the rules.**